# Acessing Non-Public base property in C#

Tags: c#, reflection, properties, visual-studio-2013

I'm currently working with a third party library and try to implement it into a C# Winforms application. I'm currently stuck because I'm not able to access all the properties I need of an object this library creates. But when I'm debugging in Visual Studio and explore the object, I can clearly see the property I'd have to access. It's the "CreateThreadId" property you can see on this picture:

[image]

I tried some things out using reflection:

```
sender.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).Single(pi => pi.Name == "CreatedThreadId");
```

But to be honest I'm a beginner using reflection and I cnt find a way to get rid of that.
Is there a way to access this property? How to do that?

Comment: Have you tried calling that code you posted on `typeof (AxLogic)`? I don't see anything wrong with it otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

`object.GetType()` will return actual runtime type of the instance, that doesn't work well with `BindingFlags.NonPublic`. If you need to access the base class's non public members you need to use base class's `Type` instance in order to make `BindingFlags.NonPublic` work.

If it is your immediate base type then you can do this.

```
var propertyInfo = sender.BaseType.GetType()
                         .GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                         .Single(pi => pi.Name == "CreatedThreadId");
```

If it is not the immediate base class you need to get the type of the class which declares the property and then use

```
var propertyInfo = typeof(BaseClassYouNeed).GetProperties()...;
```